# Allow user to specify webhook URI

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created an Agent using API.ai and was wondering if it's possible to prompt the user in the Google Home app for the webhook URI. My use case involves multiple users each with their own instance of a web service that they maintain. I'd like for the agent to be public, but allow the users via the Google Home app or otherwise to specify the webhook URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google needs to make sure that all of the webhooks it uses can be traced to an authorized identity, so it isn't likely that they would implement a way to directly let people attach their own webhooks to your agent.

The most obvious work-around would be to allow people to create accounts with your service and register the webhooks with you. Then you would serve as a proxy between the Google Assistant and their implementation.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. This was my initial thought as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! Prompt the user for their webhook and tie it to their account within your app.

When requests arrive from their account have your app call their webhook

[view example here](https://fastur.com/#actions)